# Solve the system of equations for $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve this system of linear equations:

$3x^2 - 12y = 0$

$24y^2 -12x = 0$

for $x$ and $y$, but I'm a little confused. I get $x = 0, 2$ and when I plug those into my first equation I get $y = 0, 1$ but when I plug it into my second equation I get $y = 0, 1, -1$.

I thought these are supposed to be equivalent. How could I determine which solutions are correct?

Comment: Divide the top equation by 3, solve for $y$.  Divide the bottom equation by 12, and plug in the solution for the top equation.

Comment: While a graph alone may not be sufficient in terms of "work", it is often helpful to rule out extraneous solutions and it helps to the learning experience. Graph both formuas in DESMOS and see what is going on

Comment: This is a *nonlinear* system of equations.

Comment: @Juxtaglo When you ask a question, it is better to show your steps in full so that others can see you haven't made a mistake.

Comment: Those are *possible* answers.  Not certain answers.  If $x =2$, then the first equation if $12-12y =0$ and $y$ is *certainly* equal to $1$.  And int the second equation $24y^2-24=0$ and $y^2 = 1$ and $y$ *COULD* be $1$ ***OR*** it *COULD* be $-1$.  But we can rule out $y=-1$ because the first equation only gave us $y=1$.  So the only option left is $y=1$ and that is possible. Not just possible, we know it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you substitute $x = 2$ in your second equation, you get $y = -1, 1$. However, $(2, -1)$ only satisfies the second equation and not the first, but $(2, 1)$ and satisfies both equations. Therefore, the only *real* solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(2, 1)$. As others have shown, your method neglects any *complex* solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between what you know what *MUST* be true, with what *MIGHT* be true.  ANd you need to learn how to determine if one set possibilities are possible but not certain, and another set of possibilities are possible but not certain, then only the ones that are common to both are possible.

Example:

We know that $3x^2 -12y=0$.  That is *ABSOLUTELY* true.  And we know that $24y^2 -12x = 0$.  That is *ABSOLUTELY* true.

Since $3x^2 -12y=0$ is without any doubt true then $y=\frac 14x^2=(\frac 12 x)^2$ is definitely true and as $24y^2 - 12x=0$ is certainly true then $24(\frac 12x)^4 - 12=0$ and $16(\frac 12x)^4 - 8x = 0$ and $x^4 - 8x = 0$.

That we know *MUST* but true.

ANd now we have to speculate what *MIGHT* be true.

$x(x^3-8)=0$ means *EITHER* $x = 0$ or $x= 2$ but we don't know which one.

*IF* $x=0$ we have $3x^2 -12y =-12y= 0$ and $y=0$. and $24y^2 -12x =24y^2 = 0$ and $y=0$.  So *If* $x = 0$ then $x=0$ and $y=0$ *might* be a solution.

And if $x=2$ then $3x^2 -12y =12-12y =0$ and so $y = 1$. So $x=2; y=1$ might be a solution.

And if $x=2$ then $24y^2 - 12y= 24y^2 - 24 =0$ and $y^2 = 1$ so $y$ *MIGHT* be equal to $1$ or $y$ *MIGHT* be equal to $-1$.

But from one equation we got if $x = 2$ then $y=1$.  And from the other we got if $x=2$ then $y$ MIGHT be $1$ OR it might be $-1$.

Well, that's not a contradiction.  If in one case we got it'd have to be $1$ and the other case it *could* be $1$ or something else but in the first case it couldn't be the something else... then the first case tells us which of the choices for the second case is right and which is wrong.  $y = 1$ and $y=-1$ is wrong.  It *might* have been right.... but it wasn't.

So the solutions.

It *might* be $x=y=0$.  Or it *might* be $x =2; y=1$.  But $x=2; y=-1$ or any other are all not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more vigorous solution is to first set the two equations:

$$3x^2 - 12y = 0\text{ (1)}$$
$$24y^2 -12x = 0\text{ (2)}$$

and first, solve for $y$ in (1), which is $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$. Substituting this into the (2) yields:

$$\frac{3x^4}{2}-12x=0$$
$$3x^4-24x=0$$
$$3x(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=0\text{ (3)}$$

Solving (3) yields the answers $x=0,2$ from and $x=-1+\sqrt{3}i,-1-\sqrt{3}i$ from using the quadratic formula on the right bracket. Keep in mind that in this context, $i=\sqrt{1}$. Plugging these $x$ values back into either (1) or (2) and solving for $y$ yields the solutions $(x,y)$ to be:

$$(x,y)=(0,0)$$
$$(x,y)=(2,1)$$
$$(x,y)=(-1+\sqrt{3}i,-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$
$$(x,y)=(-1-\sqrt{3}i,-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$

Even though (2,-1) appears to be a solution, we can rule it out as an extraneous solution as it does not satisfy both equations. Therefore all solutions to your simultaneous equation can be seen above.